# How do I enable writing in Indian languages?

Tags: language-support, input-language

I am looking for a step by step method for enabling write in indian languages (hindi and gujarati) in Ubuntu applications (browser, LibreOffice, Pidgin etc..).

Could anyone please provide me a method for beginner to do it or simply direct me to the one if you know?

Comment: Duplicate of [Indian languages in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765807/indian-languages-not-suppoted-in-ubuntu-16-04/985886#985886)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## For Ubuntu 18.04 and above

The menus and settings have changed changed significantly since Ubuntu 17.10 and above uses Gnome Shell instead of Unity. These instructions may work for Ubuntu 17.10 as well, but I have only tested them in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

### Use a Hindi keyboard:

1. Go to **System Menu** at the top right corner of the desktop panel and
   select **Settings**, the screwdriver & wrench icon.

   [image: settings menu]
2. Select **Region & Languages**
3. Click the **<kbd>+</kbd>** icon under the **Input Sources** to open **Add an Input Source** window.

   [image: Region & Language menu]
4. Click on the three dots at the bottom of the window to expose the
   search bar.

   [image: three dots below already configured languages in Input Source list]
5. Type **Hindi** or any other language you want to install.
   The word **Other** will show on the top of the Window.
6. Click on **Other** different keyboard layouts for Hindi (or the language you typed) will show below it.

   [image: searching the list]
7. Select a keyboard layout and press the <kbd>Add</kbd> button at the top.

   [image: green button appears when layout is selected]

   Now the new keyboard layout will be listed in the **Input Sources** table.

   [image: Input Sources list in Region & Languages lists Hindi]

That's it!

### For Gujarati and other Indian languages

**Repeat the steps above.**

There is only one keyboard layout available by default for Gujarati.

Check the keyboard layouts you selected first select the language from the list of input sources. Then click on the keyboard icon at the bottom right corner.

You can also see the keyboard layouts of any installed language from the drop-down menu of the language icon on the top right corner of the desktop.

### Use `ibus-m17n`, the preferred method

If you don't see the keyboard layout you want, or **if you get unexpected results when you type in the selected language** then follow the steps below install `ibus-m17n`. This will give you more choices of keyboard layouts in your Indian language.

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

   ```
   sudo apt install ibus-m17n
   ```
2. Enter your password when prompted.
3. Close all applications and **restart the computer** for the
   `ibus-m17n` based keyboard layouts to show up in the list. Follow the
   same steps to select a different keyboard layout.

### Changing between keyboard layouts

Once a new keyboard layout is selected, you will see a new language icon at the top panel. Clicking it will give you all the installed keyboard layout choices. You can also switch between different installed keyboard layouts by clicking <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

## Instructions for older versions of Ubuntu

## For Ubuntu 16.04

### Install language support

Go to **System Settings > Language Support > Install Languages** and  install Hindi (or any other Indian language).

### Use a Hindi keyboard:

1. Go to the Keyboard app. If you have Unity or something that allows you to search for your apps, then get to it that way. Otherwise it's probably in **System » Preferences » Keyboard**.
2. Go to Text Entry at the bottom of the Typing tab. Click add, and find Hindi (it's easier by language than by country).
3. Choose a keyboard layout you are comfortable with. The program will display the layout so you can confirm the one that suits you best. Examples of keyboard layouts are `Bolnagiri`, `KaGaPa`, `Phonetic`, and `Wx`. different layouts assign different <kbd>keys</kbd> to different letters. Choose the keyboard layout you are used to, or try a few and see which one you like best. Here are some [examples of Hindi keyboard layouts](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/I18N/Indic/HindiKeyboardLayouts#Itrans_Keyboard_Layout).
4. A little icon on the top panel displays a small keyboard icon and the current keyboard layout. It's probably still the English language one, since you haven't yet chosen to write in Hindi. So, to start writing in Hindi, click on that icon and choose the Hindi layout. You can now start typing in Hindi.

**Repeat for Gujarati.** When you do it for the first time, it will ask permission to install some software. Say yes and enter password when needed.

### Use `ibus-m17n`, the preferred method

1. Using Ubuntu Software Center **install ibus-m17n.** This will give
   you more Hindi keyboard layout choices. This may be already
   installed.
2. Once you installed iBus, open Dash and look for iBus. Once iBus is
   running, go to the second tab called input method.
3. Make sure "Customize Input Selection Method" is checked. Click on
   Select and Input Method  and select **Hindi > itrans.** Then hit the
   Add button to add this input method. If Hindi is not at the top, click on it and click "Up" button to move it to the top. Click on close button. You will
   notice a keyboard icon on the top panel in Unity.

## Some hints on typing in Hindi (Itrans)

Now, open a new window of LibreOffice or Gedit or where ever you want to type in Hindi and hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space Bar</kbd>. This will change the input method to Hindi for that app. You will notice that the icon on the tray now shows Hindi क्. If you don't see क् and see the keyboard icon or another language icon on the top panel, click on it and select Hindi-Itrans (m17n). Now type "kaise ho" it should appear in Hindi.

Note the Itrans phonetic layout has its own rules so it may not be exactly what you are used to. There is a Gujarati-Itrans choice as well in the ibus Input selection method.

[More detailed instructions with pictures](http://www.muktware.com/articles/3268/how-type-hindi-ubuntu).

See the answer to [How to type half Hindi character with Hindi (Bolnagri) layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367761/how-to-type-half-hindi-character-with-hindi-bolnagri-layout/367811#367811)

Hope this helps.

Comment: wow! that worked!! तुम्हारा बहुत् धन्यवाद user68186! have you found where anuswar is? I mean, which key represents the bindi as in बदर् (monkey)? Anyway, I am quite happy to find what I wanted. I didn't think it would be so easy! Thanks a lot.

Comment: ...found it. its capital m (M).

Comment: Thank you very much, Use Hindi(Wx) layout its better than Hindi(Bolnagri)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in 14.04 I can't find iBus. Cant search it in dash. Also if you can tell which key combination brings the "Poorn Viraam"

Comment: @GunJack It looks like ibus does not show up in Dash search any more in 14.04. However you should be able to switch between keyboards by icon on the top right, or by pressing Super+space. Pressing period (.) should give you "poorn viram."

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have added a 18.04 section and revised the rest of the answer. Feel free to comment and edit. I get more options to "Install/Remove Languages" under **Manage Installed Languages" I am not sure if adding a language this way has any additional advantage, such as spell checks if available. In my limited testing I could type in the Indian languages without adding it via **Manage Installed Language."

Comment: @Zanna Thanks for the edits.

Comment: Any time! Still trying to figure out how to type Tamil in Lubuntu... might have to ask a question

Comment: @Zanna Sorry, I don't know how. I am sure someone else would know.

Answer (score 4):

In order to type Indian languages or any other languages in Linux 11.1 and above, one need to install fonts of those languages and keyboard input method amd ibus m17n

For Indian languages open terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-indic-fonts
sudo apt-get install ibuspressing both keys 
sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n
```

Restart the computer. Then from the dash (press <kbd>Super</kbd>) select System Settings and then Language Support (close any other window jf appears).

Goto keyboard input method system and choose `ibus` from the list to enable `ibus`.

Then from dash, search and select Keyboard Input Methods and and right click on icon, if it is not installed select install.

After this select Keyboard Input Methods and select launch, Ibus preferences menu will appear.

In "General" tab, mark for show icon on the system tray.

Now select second tab "Input Method", mark Customize active input methods then select an input method from the list (click on list icon to select from the language list) like Gujarati (choose one of these- in-script, itran or phonetic) selected language will appear under Customize active input methods.

Then click add option on the right side. For Hindi select Hindi -> (choose one option from 6 options, select `phonetic m17n` to type as you speak; भारत = Shift + bart) and click add next to it. Close the ibus preference menu.

Like this one can select any language from the list and add to language panel.

In any editor to activate desired language click on the language panel (right top corner of the screen) and select language in which you want to type. When you select language, icon will change to that language. To type in English select option - input method off.

In older version of Linux, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, activates and deactivates the desired language.

Answer (score 1):

The Hindi language keyboard code is ***`hi`*** and the Gujarati is ***`gu`***

To add the support

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,hi
```

Or

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,gu
```

Keep in mind that the above will go away once you reboot.

Using GUI open System settings, go to keyboard layout, and add the layout that you desire.

[image]

Comment: @kamyogi: if it works, please consider accepting the answer (check mark on left) to close it as "answered". Good luck and welcome to Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, it worked (thanks for the nice explanation by everyone) but it doesn't suit me, so given up. The keyboard layout is not the same as I used to use in Windows. I am rather looking for a way to write as it sounds phonetically. For example, press keys 'kaise ho' to write as it sounds. Anyway, thanks for the attempt. @user68186

Comment: Did you try the Hindi (Wx) layout? It is phonetic.

Comment: I don't know Hindi, but I'll try it and let you know, based on your example above.

Comment: As per your example kaise ho is क्िसे हो.  Is that what you want?

Comment: kaise ho didn't turn out quite the way it should be: कैसे हो. We may be missing a step or two.

Comment: @user68186 That's right. 'kaise ho' doesn't seem to be well written in hindi in your first try as you can see. I tried both hindi layouts available on Ubuntu. Earlier, I used Indic Input Method Editor (IME) on Windows and it worked perfectly well. I am looking for something similar. By the way, thanks to you both (you and Mitch) a lot for willing so much to help me. I am quite pleasantly surprised having this prompt and tailored service.

Comment: @kamyogi You are welcome. See my edited answer regarding using ibus and the Itrans layout. I am not familiar with Windows input method layout, so I can't say if this is similar or not, but it is another phonetic layout. Give it and others a try and see which one suits you best. By the way, we are just users like you, helping each other. Best

Answer (score 0):

Press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

The terminal window opens

Type

```
sudo synaptic
```

The synaptic window opens

[image]

Go to the search tool and search for the package `iok`

[image]

In the window that appears tick the box left to `iok`

[image]

Click on mark for installation

[image]

Click on Apply

[image]

Again click on Apply

[image]

Click on Close

[image]

Now search for ibus

[image]

In the window that appears search for ibus and tick the box to the left of it

[image]

Click on mark for installation

[image]

Click on apply

[image]

Again click on apply

[image]

Click on close

[image]

Close Synaptic

Go to settings

[image]

System Settings window opens, go to Language Support icon and click on it

[image]

In the Language Support window that appears click on Install/Remove languages

[image]

Browse for Hindi and tick on the box right to it.

[image]

Click on apply

[image]

Close Language Support and System Settings Windows

Go to Dash

[image]

Type iok and click on the iok icon that appears

[image]

iok -Indic Onscreen Keyboard opens

[image]

In the Right Bottom select hindi-inscript

[image]

New keyboard layout appears

[image]

Open libreoffice or gedit or any other text editor application

Press the key combination

<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>

start typing in Hindi

नमस्ते, मेरा नाम रैन्चो है|

Again to switch back to English typing press the key combination

<kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>