# ibus-avro is not working in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ibus, internationalization

I was using ibus-avro with ibus input method to write Bengali in Ubuntu 12.04. Recently I have upgraded Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10, now ibus-avro was removed. I have tried to install it again but was getting error message as follows

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have  
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable  
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created  
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:  

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
ibus-avro : Depends: gir1.2-gjsdbus-1.0 but it is not installable
```

Comment: You need **ibus m17n**. See the alternate part of the answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages/165650#165650

Comment: I have `ibus m17n` installed, and I can use other `ibus` bengali keyboard like `itrans`, `prabhat`. But those are not exactly as powerful as `avro`. That's why I am trying to install `ibus-avro` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I am able to install it. I have compiled it from the source without installing `gir1.2-gjsdbus-1.0` and till now it is working perfectly.
First install the bellow mention packages using the code.

> sudo apt-get install git ibus libibus-1.0-dev automake autoconf gjs gir1.2-ibus-1.0

Now install the following code to download, compile and install the `ibus-avro`

> git clone git://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro.git
>   cd ibus-avro
>   aclocal && autoconf && automake --add-missing
>   ./configure --prefix=/usr
>   sudo make install

I have found this instruction from in this link
https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/blob/master/README.md

You may notice that I have omitted the package "gir1.2-gjsdbus-1.0" which is told by Sarim in the comment of an issue, you can check it in the following link
https://github.com/sarim/ibus-avro/issues/37

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution from here.... just do what it tells you to do and compile the sources as described....
 http://forum.linuxdesh.org/thread-1088.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The problem is I can not install `gir1.2-gjsdbus-1.0` in Ubuntu 12.10. That is what my the error message is showing in my question above. Any way thanks for you comment @Nazmus