# How to type in Kannada language in LibreOffice?

Tags: input-method

In previous releases, the following packages were supported:

1. scim
2. scim-bridge-agent
3. scim-bridge-client-gtk
4. scim-bridge-client-qt4
5. scim-m17n
6. scim-modules-table

However, they are not available in Quantal's repositories from 2012-09-24. How do we use `ibus` instead?

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it like this : [**How to edit , read kannada documents created on microsoft word with Nudi Ekabhashe fonts on ubuntu? And vice versa?**](http://askubuntu.com/a/725818/497359)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable writing in Indian languages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages)

Answer (score 5):

1. First remove all the said scim pacakages, im-config.
2. Install the "ibus" ,"Adjust methods for keyboard input"tools.

---

Make sure to install the following pakages

1. ibus-m17n
2. ibus-table-extraphrase
3. ibus-gtk
4. ibus-gtk3
5. ibus-qt4
6. ibus-table
7. ibus-clutter

---

Choose the input method switch and make ibus as the choice.
A dialalogue box to restart X session appears choose ok.
Log out and login back to restart X session.
Go to ibus system tray icon choose preferences 
click input method tab and  kannada option which has kgp(nudi) ,inscript(nudi),itrans(baraha format)
choose them to the add to list .---done---
**------Usage------** 
Open gedit  writer the press control space  and write in kannada
**For Libreoffice** 
Click on Tools → Options → Language settings → Languages
Check Enabled for Complex Text Layout(CTL) and Choose Kannada in Default
languages for Documents (CTL)
**Enjoy kannada typing!**

Answer (score 2):

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10. IBus is installed by default. So, now just go to System Settings > Text Entry. Add Kannada phonetic as an input source. Now you can type Kannada easily. Use <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to switch between languages. The Kannada phonetic keyboard is similar to Nudi on Windows.

*Enjoy typing in Kannada.*

Comment: Please replace these funny symbols with English ones.

Comment: They are not funny symbols. The script is in Kannada. The sentences mean- "Type in Kannada. Enjoy."

Comment: I knew that they mean something. :) By my remark I meant that it would be better to avoid native language messages in English-based forum.