# How to edit , read kannada documents created on microsoft word with Nudi Ekabhashe fonts on ubuntu? And vice versa?

Tags: libreoffice

How to read, edit Kannada documents created on Libreoffice with Unicode fonts (kedage lohit etc) on Microsoft word in Windows.How to ensure inter-operability in both ways?

Answer (score 2):

**The best method to ensure inter-operability between both systems is as follows**

1.For reading ,editing kannada(or any other) documents created on Microsoft Word with Nudi
on Libreoffice Writer
It is possible to **read** documents created with Nudi in MS Word on LibreOffice Writer by installing(copying) the Nudi fonts(available with Nudi5 installer zip) in **/usr/share/fonts**
(with root permission and read acess to users) and do

```
fc-cache
```

LibreOffice application will have Nudi fonts in it.
However it is not possible to **edit** Nudi fonts on LibreOffice installed on Ubuntu
only Lohit kedage fonts will appear

Therfore to both **read and edit under one hood** the best solution is to install latest  Wine program 
and on that install LibreOffice.exe Windows executable also install Nudi 5.exe program on Wine 
 use scroll lock to write Nudi text in LibreOffice.This way all fonts work for both **read and edit**
**2.** To read, edit Kannada documents created on Libreoffice with Unicode fonts (kedage lohit etc) on Microsoft word in Windows.Install all unicode fonts on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

## you can try this:

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y`
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> `sudo apt-get install wine`

Or you can just install it from Ubuntu Software center : [Wine on software center](http://apt://wine1.4)

- After this download Nudi from here : [ಕನ್ನಡ ತಂತ್ರಾಂಶ Nudi ಆವೃತ್ತಿ 4.0 ಡೌನ್ಲೋಡ್ (NUDI 4.0)](http://www.karunadu.gov.in/bims/nudi4r3setup.zip)
- Now install Nudi as you do on windows. (It will be installed on wine virtual C drive)
- Now you have **two options**: Either Download **MsOffice 2007** (not any other version) or download **[libre office for windows](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=win-x86&version=5.0&lang=en-US)**
- Now install Ms Office or libre office of windows version on Ubuntu with the help of Wine.
- Now you can edit kannada files as Shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/0GmT0a3b_mc)

Comment: Video link : [youtube](https://youtu.be/0GmT0a3b_mc)

Comment: Libre Office windows version : [Libre.exe](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=win-x86&version=5.0&lang=en-US)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ensuring compatibility always, can be a Herculean task. **Wine** is a good way of getting **Nudi** work nicely on a Linux machine.

Another way is to simply use a **Windows Virtual Machine** with Linux Ubuntu host. There will be no problems with the formatting and fonts whatsoever(better to say least problems :P), as you will be working in a Windows environment itself.

You may refer this video to see it in action:
[Kannada Typing-NUDI in Ubuntu/Linux(Virtual Machine) ಲಿನಕ್ಸ್/ಉಬುಂಟು ನಲ್ಲಿ ನುಡಿ](https://youtu.be/nzTJYE28c5Q)

Answer (score 0):

The easy method will be convert it to unicode using any online converter [Click here](https://aravindavk.in/ascii2unicode/) and then copy paste it. This works well with google docs too.

When I copied a word document written in kannada to google docs, the letters were unreadable "J®ègÉÆ¼ÀUÉÆAzÁUÀÄ"
What helped me was that i copied this exact text to the site provided above and clicked on convert. It gave me the readable kannada text back "ಎಲ್ಲರೊಳಗೊಂದಾಗು". Hope this helps. Thank-you