# Hindi traditional or inscript keyboard layout not available

Tags: keyboard-layout

I do not want to use Hindi(bolnagri) or Hindi(Wx) phonatic layouts. Is Hindi inscript or traditional layout available for ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable writing in Indian languages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages)

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you can use a keyboard layout called "Indian".  I am new to Hindi (started a self-study of it last month), but from looking at images on the net for InScript and comparing it to what I see for "Indian" they look the same.

To get the "Indian" keyboard layout, I went to "System Settings" then chose "Text Entry" then selected the "+" to add an "input source" and selected "Indian" from the list.

I checked that "Indian" board a bit. All the keys seem right except for the 5, 6, 7, and 8 keys are not mapped as shown in the images I found. So I do not know how you would access the characters normally accessible there.

[image: Missing characters]

Comment: ये काम करता है। (It works!)

Answer (score 1):

With Indian group and Default layout variant you can type 4 different gliphs by 1 phisycal button plus 2 key modifiers **right Alt** and **any Shift**. So top-leftmost button near **Esc** (~) example:

```
just press: ॊ
with Shift:ऒ
with R-Alt:`
with R-Alt+Shift:~
```

This Indian - Default layout mostly the same as **InScript** but with some differences. For example the button just left from backspace let you type this 4 gliphs:  ृऋ ॄॠ; no more + and =. Use **R-Alt** and **Shift** key modifiers to find out all differences by your own.

I don't know the real name of this InScript clone layout.

OS: Kubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

```
श + ् + र = श्र
क + ् + ष = क्ष
त + ् + र = त्र
ज + ् + ञ = ज्ञ
```

You can combine existing words to form these. It is a bit lengthy but works..