# Typing in Marathi on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, keyboard-layout

I am using the latest version of Kubuntu. I am trying to figure out how to type in Marathi in various office programs. I tried ibus before. It worked in a text editor and a browser but did not work in Libre Office. I found the simplest answer here [How do I enable writing in Indian languages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages)
However, I cannot find any indian language in the list when I want to add that keyboard layout.
Do I need to update this list by downloading some package? Please help me out with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Search m17n in Software center and install it. (https://github.com/ibus/ibus-m17n)

It is phonetic keyboard.