# How to write gujarati word in gedit

Tags: input-language

I need to write gujarati language in ubuntu 14.04

I want to type gujarati in my system. I am using 14.04 ubuntu linux

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable writing in Indian languages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages)

Answer (score 0):

Try [This font](http://saumil.net/howto/gujfont/Saumil_guj2.ttf).

Download and open as usual, click "Install font"

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Install these packages:

  sudo apt install ibus-m17n ttf-gujarati-fonts
- Log out and log in again
- [Use Text Entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html) to enable one of the **Gujarati (... (m17n))** input sources.