# Indian languages not suppoted in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, language-support

I noticed that some Indian languages (eg : Kannada) are not supported in Ubuntu 16.04.

See this screenshot:
[image]

Even with file names :

[image]

This was not happening in earlier Ubuntu editions. How can I enable kannada in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the Language Support in System Settings:

[image]

Click on the 'Install/Remove Languages' button:

[image]

Click the checkbox next to the language of your choice and click 'Apply'.

Comment: this corrected only kannada (I installed only kannada) I dont want to install all the Indian languages. I never installed anything on Ubuntu 14.04 or 15.10 : all languages were displayed properly

Comment: @SeverusTux Any Idea how to use Arkavatu in Kannada?

Answer (score 7):

You can install related fonts. Like in your case you would need Indian fonts. From terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-indic
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that as from Ubuntu 17.10 the `fonts-indic` meta package, and with that fonts for many Indian languages, is installed by default.

Answer (score 4):

(Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with these languages)

Try system settings > language support, and check if the languages you need is fully installed. Sometimes some language packages may not be installed.

If that does not work, try to install `fonts-knda` for Kannada language and `fonts-telu` and see if that fix it. You can install from Synaptic or use this terminal command:

`sudo apt install fonts-knda fonts-telu`

Comment: `Unable to locate package fonts-knda`

Answer (score 2):

### For new Ubuntu 16.04 installation

Follow the steps given by @Bharadwaj Raju (installing Language Pack from SystemSetting > LanguageSupport > Install/RemoveLanguage > find and MARK kannada language pack for installation > apply system wide > restart ubuntu)

PS : Please update your system before going for language package installation or removal.

### Upgraded from previous versions to Ubuntu 16.04

If you have upgraded from previous versions to Ubuntu 16.04 (like me), language packages will be there itself (if you choose to leave currently installed applications there itself while upgrading).

You just have to *remove kannada language pack > apply system wide > restart ubuntu > add language pack again*

For me installing **Synaptic Package Manager** and installing **fonts-knda** as mentioned by @user541021 worked well, followed by a system restart.

---

[If you want to type like in Nudi,after getting kannada language pack installed;

*SystemSetting > Text Entry > plus icon > add **Kannada (kgp (m17n)) (ibus)** > system restart*

Next time you switch languages using shortcut key or clicking **EN** button on the top right corner, you'll be easily able to input kannada language (since it's unicode, it'll work even on browser without any issue) ]

[I cannot find which language the left side marked one is, probably telugu. Can someone confirm?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djNEm.jpg)