# How to type chinese, japanese and korean in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: keyboard, input-language, japanese, chinese, korean

I am trying to use [fcitx](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Fcitx) but getting nowhere.

I can see the keyboard icon on the top-right of screen, but no matter what input method option I chose, I'm still typing english.

The only way I can type is by using the virtual keyboard which is painful.

All posts I've read so far are about installing but nothing about using.

Comment: Do you have the languages enabled? See my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/765807/indian-languages-not-suppoted-in-ubuntu-16-04/765811#765811), might help you.

Comment: The document [Use alternative input sources](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html) in the official documentation, especially the last section, provides the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Try going back to your text-entry. Click the wrench/driver 'x' button. Pay attention to the toggle key.

Now click on your desired language icon at your icon bar. Then use the toggle button shortcut.

Comment: You answer could be made clearer with screen snapshots and more details.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that with Ubuntu. Can you teach me?

Comment: I can't answer your question by posting an answer to your answer. Post a new question in AskUbuntu with the title "How can I take a screen picture" (I use Alt+Print Screen) or search existing questions to see if someone has already asked this. For example: (This one) [http://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available]