# Issues with Remington Hindi Keyboard Layout (m17n), Small diacritical sign in hindi using remington keyboard layout is shifting to previous character

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, ibus

Remington Hindi Keyboard Layout not working properly in Ubuntu 16.04 - Hindi-Remington (m17n)

while typing on Remington layout in Ubuntu some of the text is not being rendered correctly, for example:

कार्यालय became कायार्लय, पुलिस became पिलुस

I have installed i-bus and selected Hindi-Remington (m17n), while typing in Windows in the same layout it is working properly,  Please help to resolve.

Comment: If you haven't already, try to install the `fonts-deva` fonts package.

Comment: Hi Swarup :), did you find the solution? probably you have been referred https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages this already

Comment: Hi Gunnar, I Installed fonts-deva and tried but it is not working as required.

Comment: I have used following command, you may also try to execute these to get the updated version?
`sudo apt-get install fonts-indic`
`sudo sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n`

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue in Ubuntu. To write "पुलिस", first of all write "पु", then "ल" and then use "ि". For "कार्य", first write "का", then "र" and then "य". This is the difference between dev Lys and Remington.