# Remington Hindi Keyboard Layout (m17n) not working properly in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, libreoffice

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS & LibreOffice Version 7.3.5.2
Remington Hindi Keyboard Layout not working properly in Ubuntu 22.04 - Hindi-Remington (m17n)
while typing on Remington layout in Ubuntu some of the text is not being rendered correctly, for example:
और became आैर, ई became र्इ
To write "और", first of all write "अ", then "ा" then “ै”
I have installed i-bus and selected Hindi-Remington (m17n), Please help to resolve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues with Remington Hindi Keyboard Layout (m17n), Small diacritical sign in hindi using remington keyboard layout is shifting to previous character](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845075/issues-with-remington-hindi-keyboard-layout-m17n-small-diacritical-sign-in-hi)

Comment: You may try another keyboard layout such as Bolnagri, KaGaPa-Phonetic, or Wx.