# How to type in Hindi using Libre Office Writer

Tags: libreoffice

I'm currently using Libre Office 5.
I was hoping someone here can help me out.

Comment: Is it the same in LibreOffice as in OpenOffice?

Answer (score 0):

Use google input tools online and then paste it in the libre office or try following links -

1. [How do I enable writing in Indian languages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages)
2. https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/16687/how-to-type-in-hindi/?answer=19400#post-id-19400