# Type in kannada language in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, language-support

I want to type in English as well as in [Kannada language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada) when needed, but I'm unable to do it.
There are some answers for the same question, but it is not the same in Ubuntu 18.04.

So please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable writing in Indian languages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1070122/edit) your question and add details like error messages, and what goes wrong. What does "unable to do it" mean? Are the letters invisible? Do the letters appear wrong? Can you not write compound letters? Which keyboard layout have you tired? Have you installed Kannada language support? Please edit your question and indicate if you have tried the answer in the link above, and if so, where do you get stuck? Which step you are unable to do?

Comment: ನಾನು ಬರೆದಿದ್ದೆಲ್ಲಾ ಸರಿಯಾಗಿ ಬರುವುದಿಲ್ಲಾ.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know Kannada, and can't figure out what is wrong with what you have written. Please edit the question and and add more details based on my questions in the above comments.

Comment: @user68186: For a number of reasons the answers to the duplicate question are obsolete for 18.04 and not very helpful to answer this question: 1. Kannada can no longer be installed via _Language Support_, 2. Indic fonts are installed by default, 3. Indic XKB layouts are no longer hidden by default.

Comment: @user68186: Aha, didn't notice that you wrote the accepted answer there. If you add a 'draft' 18.04 variant, I'll be happy to review it and provide feedback. Just ping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the `ibus-m17n` package. Then, after next reboot, you'll find a bunch of Kannada input source options in *Region & Language* (the "Other" section).

Comment: Yes. Many answers don't say that you should reboot to see more input sources.