# Chrome based browsers doesn't dispaly indian languages

Tags: 18.04, firefox, google-chrome, chromium

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 recently i installed dr.web antivirus and scanned my machine. It shows nothing detected then i uninstalled dr.web antivirus. Here after chrome based browsers (google chrome, chromium, opera) doesn't display  indian languages. but this issue not happen to firefox browser. any solution https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrsNq.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU0eE.jpg

Comment: this is not a solution, however I wonder if installing dr.web now gives you back the good font rendering

Comment: thanks for your replay but i'm not interested to install dr.web again

Comment: see this answer on how to reinstall Indian languages  https://askubuntu.com/a/336548/18025

Comment: It doesn't help me. because my firefox works perfectly problem with only chrome based browsers like google chrome,chromium,opera.

Answer (score 0):

I put this two commands now its working perfectly

sudo apt-get install fonts-noto
sudo apt-get install fonts-noto-cjk

for more details visit this link

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/5705492?hl=en

anyway thanks for this forum