# Telugu input (using ibus-m17n) not working correctly on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ibus, input-language

I installed ibus-m17n for using telugu input method in Ubuntu 20.04.

I selected the - Telugu (rts (m17n)) -  input source for the keyboard.

When I type any word that contains compound letters ('otthulu') they are not getting rendered correctly in Sublime Text or TextMaker but correctly in the browser/text editor. Also, I noticed that there comes a bubble with the text while typing which shows the correct compound letter ('otthu') but when the final text rendered it comes up incorrect. See the following example.

In the Sublime Text or TextMaker I typed 'amma' and it comes up as అమ్ మ (without the space) instead of అమ్మ. (also see the screenshot)

[image]

but in the Browser and Text Editor, they are coming up correctly e.g. అమ్మ, దృక్పధం.

However, the words without compound letters ('otthulu') are coming up correctly e.g. పతాకం,బేజారు

Is there a setting or something that am missing that the compound letters ('otthulu') not getting rendered correctly in the text file editors such as Text Maker and Sublime Text?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages/165650#165650).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a font configuration issue.

Assuming that you have the `fonts-telu` package installed, I suggest that you create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-prefer-telugu.conf` and give it this contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Lohit Telugu</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Lohit Telugu</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>monospace</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Lohit Telugu</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: Thank you @Gunnar Hjalmarsson, I shall check that. I doubt if I have fonts-telu package installed. I did not install manually, but the system may have installed while adding the languages. Also, on another note, the input worked for the compound letters in LibreOffice Writer/Text editor. I found out that Sublime Text and Text Maker do not support complex fonts. I doubt if that is the actual (underlying) issue.

Comment: @UreshKuruhuri: You must have some font which is capable of rendering Telugu, at least. ;) I admit that I'm not sure, but it may be worth a try. In any case it's a rendering issue, not an input issue.

Comment: I am sure I have the required Telugu fonts. I was able to type the required content in LibreOffice Writer and the default Text editor that comes in Ubuntu 20.04. I did look up in google search about Sublime Text and SoftMaker TextMaker and they both do not support complex fonts "yet". Sublime Text being more of code editor and TextMaker do not support Indic fonts yet (it is in their wishlist since a long time,,I guess since 2008). Anyway, I was able to get through my task with the other text file processors.

Comment: @UreshKuruhuri: Thanks for letting me know. Then I learned something today. :)