# How do you interpret a keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have activated the keyboard for Indian scripts as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165637/how-do-i-enable-writing-in-indian-languages).
Upon checking the keyboard layout, I find 4 symbols mapped to one key:

[image: here]

I am able to input the characters

- denoted in the bottom left of the key by pressing the key normally
- denoted in the top left of the key by pressing the key with shift

I want to access the symbols on the right side of the mapping. How can that be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can input the symbols

- on the bottom right by using **right alt**
- on the top right by using **right alt** along with **shift**.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the key you're describing as "right alt" is the one that the layout image labels "Level3 Shift"?

Comment: @Mark I believe that is the case. Sometimes, the right alt is also called [Alt Gr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)